# Python upper() function turns string lowercase

Tags: python

I have tried to write a function that returns the string with only the first letter capitalized

```
def uppercase(sentence):
    return sentence.lower().replace(sentence[0],sentence[0].upper(),1)


test1 = "how aRe yOu doiNg"
test2 = "How aRe yOu doiNg"


print(uppercase(test1))
print(uppercase(test2))
```

Problem is, this only seems to work when the input string starts with a lowercase letter.

These are the outputs:

How are you doing

how are you doing

I could not figure out why the upper() function turns a lowercase beginning letter to uppercase while turning an uppercase beginning letter to a lowercase.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Regardless of what `replace` is doing, `.lower` will return the entire string as lower case. Additionally, this can be done a lot easier with `.capitalize`

Comment: `sentence[0]` is still `'H'`, **not** `'h'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in string method, [`.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize), which does exactly what you want:

```py
test1 = "how aRe yOu doiNg"
test2 = "How aRe yOu doiNg"


print(test1.captialize()) # How are you doing
print(test2.capitalize()) # How are you doing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to manually implement `str.capitalize` the below is much clearer and works; slicing is used to handle the empty string case.

```
def uppercase(sentence):
    return sentence[:1].upper() + sentence[1:].lower()

test1 = "how aRe yOu doiNg"
test2 = "How aRe yOu doiNg"
test3 = ""

print(uppercase(test1))
print(uppercase(test2))
print(uppercase(test3))
```

Output

```
How are you doing
How are you doing
```